# Example of convex sets

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

> Give an example of an infinite family of convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that
> any $d + 1$ of them have a common point but all of them do not have.
> It is enough to find such a family for some $d$.

I am not able to understand the question here. Could someone please say what does this mean and what will be its answer?

Comment: Can you find a familiy of convex sets such that if you pick any $d+1$ of them, their intersection is not empty but the intersection of the whole family is. Try to work in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to begin.

Comment: Can you find five convex sets in the plane such that the intersection of any three of them is nonempty, but the intersection of all five is empty?

Comment: @nicomezi Thank you so much.

Comment: @EricTowers Thank you for the example. Isn't according to Helly's theorem if d+1 segments have non-empty intersection then the entire family has a non-empty intersection. I am actually getting confused. Is my approach wrong.

Comment: @nicomezi I am not able to think of any good example though.

Comment: @Dasha : You say "segments", but I set the subproblem in the plane...

Comment: @EricTowers oh! sincere apologies. Quoting Helly theorem, " Let X1, ..., Xn be a finite collection of convex subsets of Rd, with n > d + 1. If the intersection of every d + 1 of these sets is nonempty, then the whole collection has a nonempty intersection". Even though I understand it's given infinite collection but we can prove Helly's theorem for infinite collection also.

Comment: @EricTowers I am actually new to these topics so I am finding it difficult to fathom.

Comment: No the theorem is not valid for infinite collections, as my example shows. Or you might want other hypothesis, such as closed sets.

Comment: @nicomezi yup it will be an infinite family of closed segments in R such that two of them intersect. Then we can prove that all of them share a common point.

Comment: So what is the question are you actually asking ? The one written now has an answer but apparently this is not what you wanted.

Comment: @nicomezi the one you have answered. Thanks for the answer. I am trying to understand it. I hope I will be able to extend it into D- dimension and for infinite case.

Comment: What do you mean for infinite case ? For the $d$-dimension, recall that segments are still convex sets. ;)

Comment: @nicomezi oh okay. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that "having a common point" means they share at least one point.

Here is an answer on $\mathbb{R}$, I will let you do the job to expand the reasonning to arbitrary dimensions but it is not that hard if you think correctly...

Define $I_n = (0, \frac 1 n)$. Each $I_n$ is convex and any intersection of $2$ of them have a common point. But if you make the intersection of the whole family it will be empty.

Indeed, let $A$ be that intersection and suppose $x \in A$. Then $x< \frac 1n$ for all $n$ so $x\le 0$ but every non-positive element is not in $I_1=(0,1)$ for example. Hence a contradiction.